# High Availability of Services

Tags: java, linux

I want to monitor a couple of services in linux. In case they go down i want to restart them.

I'm writing a crontab which will get the name of the services using jps command every 60 seconds, and if they're not present in the resultset, issue a restart command specific to each of these services.

I want these services to be always available so in case they go down i'm able to get them up and running again.

I'm worried that in case any of these services hang up how will i know. Is there a way to know about hung services and kill them?

Is there a clean way of implementing auto restart of services which will handle both "services that go down" and "services that hang up".

Thanks

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is a place to ask programming-related questions. You might find better answers to your question at our [sister site devote to Unix and Linux issues](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just a hint, when monitoring services you not only want to know if they run, but if they are working properly, example monitoring HTTPd you want to test HTTP request so you know that the service is really running, etc.

Comment: Alternatively the more general http://www.serverfault.com which is aimed at server (and hence) service management.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, assuming that these services can be queried using the network, that you call the services via localhost and if they time out, killing them and restarting them using the killall or the pkill command.

Sorry for not explaining a lot, I hope it seems pretty straightforward...

Comment: I'm afraid that these services are not queriable

Comment: since performance is the key to this application i don't think that will be a feasible solution. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to know about hung services and kill them?

Telling for an arbitrary process whether it has hung is non-trivial. There are several things you could examine:

- Does it respond to network requests - try `curl`ing or otherwise sending a low-impact test request.
- Does it log to disk - check the log file's last updated time and kill it if it's older than X.

In the general case it's unsolvable, but those are some common pointers of things most processes do that you can check.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Perhaps `service --status-all` could help? Just grep the output and search for `[+]` which indicates it's up.</strike>

Actually, no need to that. Just call `service 'service_name' status`.

Comment: why `grep` `--status-all` and not simply use `service <x> status`?

Comment: Yup, I just saw that under `man`.

Comment: can we identify a hung service. i believe a status command will just tell me if a service is running or not.